# What is the first valid host on the subnetwork that the node 192.168.197.13 255.255.255.252 belongs to?

Tags: subnet

Does anyone have any ideas what the answer to this is?

**What is the first valid host on the subnetwork that the node 192.168.197.13 255.255.255.252 belongs to?**

I calculated the answer myself, but got the wrong value and don't know why.

Will update this with the official answer once I've had some responses.

Looking forward to seeing how you guys tackle this.

Hopefully your working will help me to see where I'm going wrong!

Comment: I got 192.168.197.13 on the network 192.168.197.12.

Comment: You're 100% right. Ok I'll update my question with how I tried to work it out and maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I see where I was going wrong now. I was somehow coming up with the wrong magic number (I think I'd been coming up with 8 instead of 4 to begin with).

Subnet mask 255.255.255.252 (/30)

Magic number = 4 (i.e. subnets increment by 4)

192.168.197.0
192.168.197.4
192.168.197.8
192.168.197.12
192.168.197.16

Therefore, 192.168.197.**13** is the first valid node on subnet 192.168.197.12

I highly recommend anyone preparing for their CCNA does lots of [practice](http://www.subnettingquestions.com/) until you can pretty much get 100% of them right. After a few hours' practice, you'll be able to answer most of them without even needing to do any working!

Answer (score 1):

The valid IPs in the range are

1. 192.168.197.13
2. 192.168.197.14

Try:
http://www.subnet-calculator.com/